# File lives on windows vs linux in Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a script that I need to run on ubuntu and windows each using Python 3.4 and when I run on windows I get an exception, *"PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\tmp9uvk57b4.txt'"* while on linux, it works error free.

I've boiled down my problem to this example snippet.   I'm not sure where the problem lies, but the snippet takes some text and writes it to a temporary file.   After a while, it removes the temp file and that is where the error comes in.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import tempfile

msg = "THIS IS A HORRIBLE MESSAGE"

txt = None

try:

    txt = tempfile.mkstemp(dir='.', suffix='.txt')[1]
    with open(txt, "w") as f:
        f.write(msg)

except Exception as exp:
    raise exp

finally:
    if txt:
        os.remove(txt)
```

I assume there is some issue where windows doesn't close the file while linux does.  Can I just explicitly close it again?   Will that mess up anything on linux?   Is there a good windows/linux gotcha resource?

Comment: You're throwing away the file descriptor from `mkstemp`, which leaves the file open without delete sharing. Thus you get a sharing violation. Why don't you use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`? That's guaranteed to be removed on Windows without having to manually delete it -- even if the process is killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tempfile.mkstemp` has two return values, an open filehandle and the filename. You don't use the open filehandle, such that it is never closed. Therefore the error message.

```
import os
import tempfile

msg = "THIS IS A HORRIBLE MESSAGE"

fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(dir='.', suffix='.txt')
try:
    with os.fdopen(fd, "w") as f:
        f.write(msg)
finally:
    os.remove(filename)
```

Comment: Quite right.   That did indeed solve my problem.     I do wonder why my original code works on ubuntu but not windows.   But, this solution works on both.

Comment: @LawfulEvil, Windows generally requires all open references to a file to share read/execute, write/append, and delete/rename access. Python normally opens files with read and write sharing, but not delete sharing. The way `os.remove` works on Windows is to open a handle with delete access and call a system function to set the file's delete disposition. The first part failed with a sharing violation because the file was already open without delete sharing. Linux/Unix doesn't have this requirement, so on Linux you were just silently leaking a file descriptor.